# Cardcom payment method for magento 2.1 loads complete success page within iframe after page redirect

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-gateway, iframe

I am creating a cardcom payment method for magento 2.1. Everything is working fine but when i try to do payment in iframe mode , then the checkout/onepage/success page gets loaded within the iframe.
what i have done in iframe is :-

```
$formHTML .='<iframe name="my_iframe" target="_parent" id="my_iframe" src="'.$this->getCardcomUrl()."&lowprofilecode=".$fields["profile"].'" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="1124px" style="border:0px"></iframe>';
```

Thus it looks something like shown in image below.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please check value of `$this->getCardcomUrl()`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was that, when page was redirected from cardcom server it was loading complete page within iframe.
Thus, finally what i did is,
after the page is redirected from cardcom server ,i redirected it again to `checkout/onepage/success` using javascript:-

```
window.top.location.href="www.xyx.com";
```

And i also added a flag in iframe `allow-top-navigation`.